# How to dynamically set key values in a JS function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with the following code:

```
var list = ['product', 'city', 'village'];

const foobar = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'foobarType',
  fields: () => ({
    product :{ // <== NOTE THAT PRODUCT IS IN THE LIST 
      type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
      args: {
        certainty:{
          type: GraphQLFloat,
          description: "tester"
        }
      },
      resolve(root,args){
        return "foobar"
      }
    }
})
```

As you can see I have a `list` with three items. In the `fields` function, you can see that I have `product`.

**How can I iterate over the list to dynamically set the `fields` functions during runtime so the result will be:**

```
var list = ['product', 'city', 'village'];

const foobar = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'foobarType',
  fields: () => ({
    product :{ // <== RESULT FROM LIST
      type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
      args: {
        certainty:{
          type: GraphQLFloat,
          description: "tester"
        }
      },
      resolve(root,args){
        return "foobar"
      }
    },
    city :{ // <== RESULT FROM LIST
      type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
      args: {
        certainty:{
          type: GraphQLFloat,
          description: "tester"
        }
      },
      resolve(root,args){
        return "foobar"
      }
    },
    village :{ // <== RESULT FROM LIST
      type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
      args: {
        certainty:{
          type: GraphQLFloat,
          description: "tester"
        }
      },
      resolve(root,args){
        return "foobar"
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your list inside the function and add each item with `object[item] = value;` syntax.

```
fields: () => {
  var fields = {};
  list.forEach(item => {
    fields[item] = {
      type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
      args: {
        certainty:{
          type: GraphQLFloat,
          description: "tester"
        }
      },
      resolve(root,args){
        return "foobar"
      }
    }
  });
  return fields;
}
```

This kind of nesting is ugly code, though. I'd prefer if you instead saved fields in a variable before passing it.

```
const fields = {};
list.forEach(item => {
  fields[item] = {
    type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
    args: {
      certainty:{
        type: GraphQLFloat,
        description: "tester"
      }
    },
    resolve(root,args){
      return "foobar"
    }
  }
});
const foobar = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'foobarType',
  fields: () => fields
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array's [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) (bracket) syntax to do this:

```
fields: () => list.map(item => ({
    [item]: {
        type: new GraphQLList(foobarType),
        args: {
          certainty:{
            type: GraphQLFloat,
            description: "tester"
          }
        },
        resolve(root,args){
          return "foobar"
        }
    }
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This indeed brings me closer. Unfortunately, it does result in: `Error: foobarType fields must be an object with field names as keys or a function which returns such an object.` though. Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: I could only test it with a simpler object as I don't have your full code. That sounds like a separate issue.